# Typescript enums with parameters

Tags: typescript, types

I'd like to have strictly typed mutable objects, exactly like the Haxe enums.

[In haxe, you can do](https://haxe.org/manual/types-enum-instance.html)

```
enum Color {
  Red;
  Rgb(r:Int, g:Int, b:Int);
  Rgba(r:Int, g:Int, b:Int, a:Int);
}
```

I'd like to be able to access the `a` parameter only if my object is a `Rgba`, and I can't access any parameters if my object is a `Red`.

I don't really care if I use the `enum` keyword or not in typescript.

Is there any way to achieve that in Typescript ?

Comment: Do you really mean “mutable”? I don’t know Haxe, but enums are pretty much universally *immutable* in other languages. Anyway, what you’re describing may be called an enum in Haxe but is generally known under different names, such as as [*sum type* or *tagged union*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union), of which enums are a special case.

Comment: How would you use it?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I really like that `taggued union`. How can I use that in typescript, in a type-safe way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 2.0, [Typescript supports tagged unions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#tagged-union-types) to some extent. The general syntax is

```
type MyType = A | B | C …;
```

Where `A`, `B` and `C` are interfaces. A `MyType` object can then be any of those types, and no other. The announcement gives a quick example:

```
interface Square {
    kind: "square";
    size: number;
}

interface Rectangle {
    kind: "rectangle";
    width: number;
    height: number;
}

interface Circle {
    kind: "circle";
    radius: number;
}

type Shape = Square | Rectangle | Circle;

function area(s: Shape) {
    // In the following switch statement, the type of s is narrowed in each case clause
    // according to the value of the discriminant property, thus allowing the other properties
    // of that variant to be accessed without a type assertion.
    switch (s.kind) {
        case "square": return s.size * s.size;
        case "rectangle": return s.width * s.height;
        case "circle": return Math.PI * s.radius * s.radius;
    }
}
```

However, the type safety if these union types needs to be guarded and checked manually with a so-called “discriminant property type guard” as the example shows (checking `s.kind`).